# Print numeric limits for multiple, varying types

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

On the following code I defined an `unsigned int` called `my_type`, which I use to print the maximum value of the type itself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
...
using namespace std;

int main() {
  typedef unsigned int my_type;

  const my_type max_int = numeric_limits<my_type>::max():

  cout << max_int << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

How can I do the same for multiple types without having to duplicate this code?

I tried creating a string array that would store types `unsigned int` and `long` (as an example), but that didn't work:

```
string current_type[2] = {"unsigned int", "long"};
loop{
  typedef current_type[0..1] my_type;
  const my_type max_int = numeric_limits<my_type>::max();
}
```

I have also tried using templates, but couldn't figure it out how to do it.

Is this even possible?

Comment: I've a sneaking suspicion that this isn't possible with C++'s type system, but I'm not so certain that I'm willing to make that an answer. A more sophisticated type system like Scala would allow it, or a language with reflection such as C# may also work.

Comment: One possible solution might be to use code generation to handle all the duplication for you.

Comment: why not `template <typename T> void printLimits() { cout << numeric_limits<T>::max() << endl;}` ?

Comment: to get it working with strings, you would need a mapping between the strings and the corresponding types. The template takes type as parameter, not a string.

Comment: @tobi303 Thanks for your suggestion, I'll need to read about how to map between the strings and the corresponding types.

Comment: ups, I am afraid you misunderstood me. I meant "if you really wanted to use strings, you would have to...", but actually I would strongly suggest you not to use strings

Comment: @tobi303, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;
template <typename T>
void printMax()
{
    cout << numeric_limits<T>::max() << endl;
}

int main()
{
    printMax<unsigned int>();
    printMax<double>();
    return 0;
}
```

And:

```
$ g++ test.cpp && ./a.out
4294967295
1.79769e+308
```

Comment: I'd give you an upvote for that, were it not for the fact that tobi303 suggested that pattern first in the comments above ;-)

Comment: @Rook thats not the point. It doesnt matter, who posted the answer, if it is the right solution, you should upvote and accept it.

Comment: Indeed.  I saw his comment just as I was pressing "Submit."

Comment: @tobi303: And an "answer" should not be a code dump without explanation.

Comment: @PreferenceBean I agree, however if I had written the answer, I also wouldnt know what/how to explain, because the OP already mentions a template solution but it is not clear, where/what was his problem. Actually I would more critize the use of `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 2):

C++ has no reflection so you can't convert c++ string to type name. But you can use variadic templates for your task.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


template <typename ... Args>
struct TL;

template <typename T>
struct TL<T>
{
    static void print()
    {
        const T max_int = numeric_limits<T>::max();
        cout << max_int << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
struct TL<T, Args...>
{
    static void print()
    {
        TL<T>::print();
        TL<Args...>::print();
    }
};

int main(int , char** )
{
    TL<int, unsigned int, short int>::print();
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

More complicated example.

You can declare variadic template for holding type lists:

```
template <typename ... Args>
struct TypeList;

template <typename T>
struct TypeList<T>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
struct TypeList<T, Args...>
{
    typedef T type;
//    typedef TypeList<Args...> rest;
};
```

and template to perform operation, depended of type for each element in type list:

```
template <typename L, template <typename T> class Op>
struct ForEach;

template <typename T, template <typename T> class Op>
struct ForEach<TypeList<T>, Op>
{
    void operator()()
    {
        Op<T>()();
    }
};

template <typename T, template <typename T> class Op, typename ... Args>
struct ForEach<TypeList<T, Args...>, Op>
{
    void operator()()
    {
        Op<T>()();
        ForEach<TypeList<Args...> , Op>()();
    }
};
```

Now, you can declare some functions like templated structs with operator()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct PrintNumericTypeMaxLimit
{
    void operator()()
    {
        const T max_int = numeric_limits<T>::max();
        cout << max_int << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct PrintNumericTypeMinLimit
{
    void operator()()
    {
        const T min = numeric_limits<T>::min();
        cout << min << endl;
    }
};
```

And use it with your type list:

```
int main(int , char** )
{
    typedef TypeList<int, unsigned int, long int, short int, unsigned short int, double> myList;
    ForEach<myList, PrintNumericTypeMaxLimit>()();
    ForEach<myList, PrintNumericTypeMinLimit>()();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Whilst you can't use reflection to, say, get a list of all the numeric types, you _can_ use `T t; string n = typeid(t).name()` to get the (implementation defined) name of a type. You could then use the same typelist or other variadic template iteration mechanism to match a user-defined string (say "i") with an internal type (`int` on my local copy of gcc). It would be a bit of a non-portable and nasty hack, but it does work.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/variant.html) to inform the types you want, [`boost::mpl::foreach`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/for-each.html) to loop over them
and a functor to print the numeric limits in a pre-c++11 manner or with a c++11 lambda

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>

struct printMaxNumLimits
{
    template<class Type>
    void operator()(Type t) {
        std::cout << std::numeric_limits<Type>::max() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    using variant_types = boost::variant<int, double, unsigned int>;

    // pre c++11
    boost::mpl::for_each<variant_types::types>(printMaxNumLimits());

    // c++11
    boost::mpl::for_each<variant_types::types>([](auto t){
        std::cout << std::numeric_limits<decltype(t)>::max() << std::endl;
    });
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1738c07aea3cbe7f)</kbd>